# Python escaping backslash

Tags: python, escaping

I'm trying to escape the backslash, but trying to understand the right way of doing it

```
foo = r'C:\Users\test.doc'
```

The above works fine

However, when I want to escape the path stored in a variable

For example :

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--source', type = str, help = 'Source file path')
```

Now, how do escape the value in - args.source

Comment: I think characters from an external source are taken literally.

Comment: Yes, but I want to escape it. Or I get a error No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\test.doc

Comment: Is that how the traceback looks?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes

Comment: how are you running this that you pass a variable?

Comment: `args.source` is populated from the command line, so you need to ensure you quote/escape things properly according to the shell you are using. In other words, it's not a Python issue, it's a shell issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape backslash and single quote or double quote in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6717435/608639)

Comment: Please read [mre]. If the traceback looks like that, then there is **nothing wrong with the code**; the problem is that the `Users` folder on the `C` drive really doesn't actually contain a file named `test.doc`. The most likely problem is that you forgot to actually include a sub-folder for *the specific user* who has that file. (and possibly also e.g. a `Desktop` sub-folder under that.) Voting to close as this does not point at a reproducible problem.

Answer (score 5):

So there are a few escape sequences to be aware of in python and they are mainly these.

[image]

So when the string for that file location is parsed by the `add_argument` method it may not be interpreted as a raw string like you've declared and there will be no way to escape the backslashes outside of the declaration.

What you can do instead is to keep it as a regular string (removing the 'r' prefix from the string) and using the escape character for a backslash in any places there may be conflict with another escape character (in this case \t). This may work as the method may evaluate the string correctly.

Try declaring your string like this.

```
foo = "C:\Users\\test.doc"
```

Hopefully this helps fix your issue!

**EDIT:**

In response to handling the dynamic file location you could maybe do something like the following!

```
def clean(s):
    s = s.replace("\t", "\\t")
    s = s.replace("\n", "\\n")
    return s
```

Until you've covered all of your bases with what locations you may need to work with! This solution might be more appropriate for your needs. It's kind of funny I didn't think of doing it this way before. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The path I get is dynamic, so I would need some sort of function to handle this.