# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: malformed \N character escape

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple error in Python with Spyder:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

ds=pd.read_csv(".\verikumesi\NBA_player_of_the_week.csv")
```

When I run the above code, the I get an error:

> File "C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/MASAÜSTÜ/github/deneme.py", line 12
>       ds=pd.read_csv(".\verikumesi\NBA_player_of_the_week.csv")
>                           ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: malformed \N character
>   escape

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python escaping backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31213556/608639) and [How to print backslash with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19095796/608639). They discuss escaping backslashes, too.

Comment: See also: [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
".\verikumesi\NBA_player_of_the_week.csv"
```

is invalid Python. In normal (non-raw) strings, the backslash combines with the following character to form an "character escape sequence", which mean something quite different. For example, `"\n"` means a newline character. There is no escape sequence `"\N"`, and you don't want an escape sequence anyway, you want a backslash and a `"N"`. One solution is to use raw strings (`r"..."`), which strip the backslash of its superpower. The other is to use a character escape sequence whose meaning *is* the backslash (`\\`).

tl;dr: Use either of these options:

```
r".\verikumesi\NBA_player_of_the_week.csv"
".\\verikumesi\\NBA_player_of_the_week.csv"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now it's working

Comment: @AliÜSTÜNEL then, please, [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you.