# How can I escape a single quote and a space in Python?

Tags: python, regex, selenium-webdriver, escaping

I am having trouble with re.search finding the string "Senders' Domains" on my UI.

```
word_check1 = 'Senders'
word_check2 = "Senders' Domains"
page_check1, page_check2 = mymessages_page.page_checker(word_check1, word_check2, 'chart-content-container')
```

When I Debug, my page_checker method finds "Senders//s Domains" but then re.search returns "Senders//sDomains" (removing the space).

```
def page_checker(self, word_check1, word_check2, ids):
    container = self.driver.find_element_by_id(ids)
    content = container.text
    organized_container_content = content.split('\n')
    for text in organized_container_content:
        if re.search(word_check1, text):
            check1 = text
            for text2 in organized_container_content:
                if re.search(word_check2, text2):
                    check2 = text2
                    return check1, check2
                    break
```

Is there any way I can escape the single quote (') and space characters so that I can find and match the string "Senders' Domains" on my UI?

Comment: single quote and space aren't special regex chars. Can you create a [mcve] to show your exact issue?

Comment: Is there any reason you should use `re.search(word_check1, text)` instead of simple `word_check1 in text`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape a ( backslash and a single quote) or double quote in python !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717435/how-to-escape-a-backslash-and-a-single-quote-or-double-quote-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the escape character '\'?  https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

```
>>> word_check2 = "Senders\' Domains"
>>> print (word_check2)
Senders' Domains
>>>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that work without escaping in your case regardless?

Comment: Thank you, this worked and helped me match the text found. @mangoHero1 is also right I tried again without escaping and it worked, so it was partly my issue of misunderstanding how re.search works.

Comment: Well, glad it worked. - was totally guessing based on your question.  I'm new and only now can I even add a comment, could only 'answer' which I think is real silly.