# How to escape a double quote inside double quoted string in python?

Tags: python, escaping, string-formatting

I have a string stored in a database-
"hello there, user "X", please help me solve this issue"

I have written an API to fetch the this entry.

Now, I want to escape the double quotes around the letter X to perform some string formatting in python.
Is there a way to write a code in python which adds the backslash before the double quotes?
I have tried using replace function, it will give invalid syntax. I just cannot use any function to escape it as it gives invalid syntax anyway.
Check the image attached for reference.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJOey.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape backslash and single quote or double quote in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717435/how-do-i-escape-backslash-and-single-quote-or-double-quote-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post pictures. About "the string stored in a database": it is not clear from your question if there are four `"` signs in the data, or only two. If there are four it is a problem because that is not a valid Python string. If there are only two then you do not need to worry about escaping. Escaping quotes is only needed in *string literals*, not when the quotes are in the data.

Comment: Based on the picture, the database mention is spurious; the string is a literal being entered at the `>>>` prompt

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
g = "hello there, user \"X\", please help me solve this issue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Code -> :

```
 print("Sammy says, \"Hello!\"")
```

Output -> :

```
 Sammy says, "Hello!"
```

So answer above is correct. You can use "\" (escape character)